# Only show hours in MYSQL DATEDIFF

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I've been busy with this for hours, but I cant get it to work.

```
SQL

SELECT DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time) as `difference` FROM timeattendance WHERE timeattendance_id = '1484'

start_time =   2012-01-01   12:00:00
end_time =     2012-01-02   13:00:00
```

The difference is 25 (hours). But the output I get is 1 (day).

How can I get the 25 hours as output?

Comment: Use `TIMEDIFF()` instead of `DATEDIFF()`

Comment: What should do for show hours and min like 25 and 30 min or  25:30

Answer (score 132, accepted):

What about using [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)?

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_time, end_time) 
           as `difference` FROM timeattendance WHERE timeattendance_id = '1484'
```

Answer (score 18):

You better use TIMEDIFF instead of DATEDIFF since DATEDIFF casts all times to dates before comparing. After performing TIMEDIFF you can obtain hours with HOUR function.

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) as `difference`;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the TIMEDIFF and HOUR function to just extract the hour.

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) as `difference` FROM timeattendance WHERE timeattendance_id = '1484'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Answer (score 6):

As stated in MySQL [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), `DATEDIFF` only takes days in account.

If both dates are after 1970, you can substract timestamps:

```
SELECT ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2012-01-02 13:00:00") - 
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2012-01-01 12:00:00") ) / 3600 ...
```

or:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF ( "2012-01-02 13:00:00", "2012-01-01 12:00:00") / 3600 ...
```