# How to select hours difference from two dates

Tags: mysql

Please how can i count the amount of hours in two given dates from my database using mysqli in php?

E.g .amount of hours between 2017/11/25 10:23 and 2017/12 20:33

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only show hours in MYSQL DATEDIFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579946/only-show-hours-in-mysql-datediff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TIMEDIFF`. it shows the difference in hours, minutes and seconds between two `DATETIME` values:

PS, your end date didn't have a day so I have used the 1st

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2017-12-01 20:33:00','2017-11-25 10:23:00')
```