# DATEDIFF to get difference in hours

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have two columns that have time data that looks like "2017-12-06 18:50:27 +0000" . What MySQL function can I use to get the difference in **hours** of the two date time strings? I tried `DATEDIFF(time_string_1, time_string_2)` but it isn't working. What else can I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only show hours in MYSQL DATEDIFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579946/only-show-hours-in-mysql-datediff)

Comment: You may use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` as the answer below shows, but you should avoid storing your timestamps as strings in the database.  Use a proper datetime type instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`timestampdiff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, col1, col2)
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

Use TIMESTAMPDIFF function.

Syntex:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)
```

Where Unit is:

```
Microseconds, Seconds, Minutes, Hours, Days, Weeks, Months, Quarters, Years.
```

Query:

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, time_string_1, time_string_2) 
from table_name
```